# Substituting elements of lists into an expression

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, expression-manipulation

Suppose I have the following lists,

```
as = {1, 2, 3, 4};
bs = {10, 20, 30, 40};
```

and the following expression:

```
a1*(b1 - a1) + a2*(b2 - a2) + a3*(b3 - a3) + a4*(b4 - a4)
```

I want to substitute the elements of my lists into my expression such that `a1 -> 1`, `a2 -> 2`, and so on and `b1 -> 10` and `b2 -> 20` and so on. I wonder how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Dot`:

```
Dot[as, bs - as]
```

> ```
> 270
> ```

```
aa = Array[Subscript[a, #] &, 4];
bb = Array[Subscript[b, #] &, 4];

Dot[aa, bb - aa] // TeXForm
```

> $a_1 \left(b_1-a_1\right)+a_2 \left(b_2-a_2\right)+a_3 \left(b_3-a_3\right)+a_4 \left(b_4-a_4\right)$

Comment: Please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224985/substituting-values-from-an-association-thread-into-a-table-of-expressions